# How do I convert a string into a Time object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I searched for my problem and got a lot of solutions, but unfortunately none satisfy my need.

My problem is, I have two or more strings, and I want to convert those strings into times, and add them:

```
time1 = "10min 43s"
time2 = "32min 30s"
```

The output will be: 43min 13s

My attempted solution is:

```
time1 = "10min 43s" 
d1=DateTime.strptime(time1, '%M ') 
# Sat, 02 Nov 2013 00:10:00 +0000 
time2 = "32min 30s" 
d2=DateTime.strptime(time2, '%M ') 
# Sat, 02 Nov 2013 00:32:00 +0000
```

Then I can't progress.

Comment: Should that output be "43min 13s" ?

Comment: What solutions have you got and why didn't they satisfy you? "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: My attempted solution :
 time1 = "10min 43s"
 d1=DateTime.strptime(time1, '%M ')
 output: Sat, 02 Nov 2013 00:10:00 +0000

  time2 = "32min 30s"
  d2=DateTime.strptime(time2, '%M ')
  output: Sat, 02 Nov 2013 00:32:00 +0000

then i cant progress then.Any idea?
Thanks @SergioTulentsev.

Comment: Is each `min` and `sec` between 0 and 59, or can they be any positive integer, in which case you might have an answer, `"4yr 3mon 2wk 6day 7hr 22min 17sec"`, or conceivably, `"22415ly ..."`.  (light years...).

Comment: Yes between 0 and 59 .
Thanks for asking @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Here's another:

```
time1 = "10min 43s"
time2 = "32min 30s"

def get_mins_and_secs(time_str)
  time_str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
    #=> [10, 43] for time_str = time1, [32, 30] for time_str = time2 
end

min, sec   = get_mins_and_secs(time1)  
min2, sec2 = get_mins_and_secs(time2)  
min += min2
sec += sec2

if sec > 59
  min += 1
  sec -= 60
end

puts "#{min}min #{sec}sec"
```

Let's consider what's happening here.  Firstly, you need to extract the minutes and seconds from the time strings.  I made a method to do that:

```
def get_mins_and_secs(time_str)
  time_str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
    #=> [10, 43] for time_str = time1, [32, 30] for time_str = time2 
end
```

For `time_str = "10min 43s",` we apply the [`String@scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method to extract the two numbers as strings:

```
"10min 43s".scan(/\d+/) # => ["10", "43"]
```

[`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) is then used to convert these two strings to integers

```
["10", "43"].map {|e| e.to_i} # => [10, 43]
```

This can be written more succinctly as

```
["10", "43"].map(&:to_i} # => [10, 43]
```

By chaining `map` to to `scan` we obtain

```
"10min 43s".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i} # => [10, 43]
```

The array `[10, 43]` is returned and received (deconstructed) by the variables `min` and `sec`:

```
min, sec = get_mins_and_secs(time_str)
```

The rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution assuming that the format stays the same:

```
time1 = "10min 43s"
time2 = "32min 30s"
strings = [time1, time2]

total_time = strings.inject(0) do |sum, entry|
  minutes, seconds = entry.split(' ')
  minutes = minutes.gsub("min", "").to_i.send(:minutes)
  seconds = seconds.gsub("s", "").to_i.send(:seconds)
  sum + minutes + seconds
end
puts "#{total_time/60}min #{total_time%60}s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
# split the string on all the integers in the string
def to_seconds(time_string)
  min, sec = time_string.gsub(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)

  min.minutes + sec.seconds
end

# Divide the seconds with 60 to get minutes and format the output.
def to_time_str(seconds)
  minutes = seconds / 60
  seconds = seconds % 60

 format("%02dmin %02dsec", minutes, seconds)
end

time_in_seconds1 = to_seconds("10min 43s")
time_in_seconds2 = to_seconds("32min 30s")

to_time_str(time_in_seconds1 + time_in_seconds2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution that takes any number of time strings and return the sum in the same format:

```
def add_times(*times)
  digits = /\d+/
  total_time = times.inject(0){|sum, entry|
    m, s = entry.scan(digits).map(&:to_i)
    sum + m*60 + s
  }.divmod(60)
  times.first.gsub(digits){total_time.shift}
end

p add_times("10min 43s", "32min 55s", "1min 2s") #=> "44min, 40s"
p add_times("10:43", "32:55") #=> "38:43"
```